# Assertion on mocked function is failing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a react component using Jest and Enzyme.

When I assert if a function is called using Jest's **.toBeCalled()**, the test is failing. I tried to trace the code by **console.log()** and I could see all the mocks are being called but the assertion is failing.

I spent a lot of time trying to dig into Just, Enzyme documentations and Stackoverflow, but couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Could you please let me if I'm doing anything wrong? Here is my code below

**Postcode.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import getPostcodeDetails from "../services/PostcodeService";
import SearchBox from "../components/searchbox/SearchBox";

let initialState = {
  statusOK: 0,
  postcode: "",
  error: ""
};

class Postcode extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    this.result = "";
    this.handleResponse = this.handleResponse.bind(this);
    this.handleError = this.handleError.bind(this);
  }

  handleResponse(response) {
    //some code
  }

  handleError(err) {
    //some code
  }

  handleSearch(postcode) {
    getPostcodeDetails(postcode)
      .then(this.handleResponse)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBox handleSearch={this.handleSearch} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Postcode;
```

**Postcode.test.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Postcode from "./Postcode";
import getPostcodeDetails from "../services/PostcodeService";

jest.mock("../services/PostcodeService");

it("handle search function", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Postcode />);
  const instance = wrapper.instance();
  const mockHandleResp = jest.fn(() => {
    console.log("Handle resp moc-");
  });
  instance.handleResponse = mockHandleResp;

  //This is a async function in a module.
  getPostcodeDetails.mockImplementation(postcode => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (postcode === "abc") {
        console.log("Resolving");
        console.log(jest.isMockFunction(resolve));
        resolve();
      } else {
        console.log("Rejecting");
        reject();
      }
    });
  });

  const mockHandleSearch = jest.fn(postcode => {
    console.log("mockHandleSearch called");
    getPostcodeDetails("abc").then(instance.handleResponse);
  });
  instance.handleSearch = mockHandleSearch;
  mockHandleSearch.call(instance);
  expect(instance.handleResponse).toBeCalled();
});
```

**Console Output**

```sh
    Console
    console.log src/containers/abc.test.js:32
      mockHandleSearch called
    console.log src/containers/abc.test.js:21
      Resolving
    console.log src/containers/abc.test.js:22
      false
    console.log src/containers/abc.test.js:34
      Promise { undefined }
    console.log src/containers/abc.test.js:13
      Handle resp moc-

  ● <Postcode> › handle search function

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

      37 |     instance.handleSearch = mockHandleSearch;
      38 |     mockHandleSearch.call(instance);
    > 39 |     expect(instance.handleResponse).toBeCalled();
         |                                     ^
      40 |   });
      41 | });
      42 |

      at Object.toBeCalled (src/containers/abc.test.js:39:37)
```

Comment: @Alex  - That didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

The `Promise` callback that calls `instance.handleResponse` hasn't run by the time `mockHandleSearch.call(instance);` returns and the `expect` runs.

### Solution

Make sure the `Promise` callbacks have a chance to complete before running the `expect`.

The easiest way to do that in this case is to make your test function `async`, return the `Promise` from `mockHandleSearch`, and `await` the returned `Promise`:

```js
it("handle search function", async () => {  // make the test function async

  ...

  const mockHandleSearch = jest.fn(postcode => {
    console.log("mockHandleSearch called");
    return getPostcodeDetails("abc").then(instance.handleResponse);  // return the Promise
  });
  instance.handleSearch = mockHandleSearch;
  await mockHandleSearch.call(instance);  // await the returned Promise
  expect(instance.handleResponse).toBeCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```